# cache a PDF file in browser

Tags: pdf, caching

How can i use the browser cache to save PDF files?
i also don't want to allow users to download or copy the cached PDF.
for example:
at first user visit address example.com/files/11 and can see the PDF file.
for next times (offline or online) if user visit that address still can see the PDF but cant download or copy the PDF file.

I've tried indexed db https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/  but id didn't work for me

i know it's impossible to prevent user from downloading the file i just want to make it harder.

**update:**
my code:

```
<?php
  header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000"); 
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  header("Content-type:application/pdf");

readfile('a.pdf');
?>
```

it works fine when a.pdf exist, but when i delete or rename a.pdf it failed to load pdf file even i enabled cache

Comment: Browsers will automatically cache all contents (files) that are not marked as not cachable. That typically is the case for static files, if that PDF document is generated in a dynamic manner this depends on the headers you yourself send. Apart from that: it simply is _impossible_ for you to prevent users from "downloading" the file, as soon as you decide to hand it out at all. It is as simple as that. you cannot at the same time publish and not publish something.

Comment: i sent cache header. it doesn't work :(

Comment: Sorry, to hear that, but please understand that "it doesn't work" has never helped anyone anywhere at any time to receive help. What does "it doesn't work" mean? _What_ headers did you send? What exactly _did_ happen? If you do not provide _precise_ details but stick with vague descriptions then we can't say any more except for the also vague explanation above.

Comment: I'm sorry. I put my code and description in question update